# Is it ok to store moment js object in redux react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, momentjs

In redux state tree How do we store dates ?

1. store moment objects in redux
2. store js date objects in redux
3. convert to ISO 8601 string and then store
4. Something better than these

ie,

```
state={
    fromTime: action.payload.fromTimeMoment,
    dateTime: action.payload.dateTimeEs6,
    toTime: action.payload.toTimeAsString,
}
```

In our current project we have stored it as moment objects, still not sure if that was the right thing to do.

Comment: Depend on are these object belongs any specific functionality or not?If then store in store else define helper utility and define getter/setter for it

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with dates I'd prefer to store as a unix format or ISO string. The reason for this is because I might want to save the state to the local storage for speed things up for second time users.

Keeping instances of other classes (or in this case moment) in the store, you might find some problems while serializing the state.

Using reselect you can create a moment instance to access the date value.

Answer (score 0):

i would just format it to epoch or the ISO string you mentioned and store it, and if its needed again convert it back to whatever you need.  its pretty redundant to store an object over and over